# Prevent cell resize in excel

Tags: vba, excel

This may seem to be a very simple question for a number of Excel users out there. Yes, I admit I am ignorant about this.

The question is quite simple.

How do I prevent manual re-sizing of a cell in Excel? In other words the user should not be able to change either the width or height of a cell / range of cells

Is this done through writing VBA code? Or can it be carried out in any other way using standard Excel menu based commands?

Thanks in advance

Romi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to 'Protect' the sheet

There are two steps:

1. Make sure the cells are locked
2. Protect the sheet

In Excel 2010

- Select the cells you want to prevent from being resized.
- Click on the Home tab and click to expand the Font section
- Select the Protection tab and make sure that the Locked box is ticked
- Click on the Review tab and then Protect sheet
- Click on the OK button

Answer (score 2):

You can lock the spreadsheet. That would prevent the user from resizing the Columns or the Rows.